# Firebase gives me Use of undeclared type with FIRDatabase and FIRDataSnapshot

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase IO example Zero to App gives me errors I can't define

```
// Firebase services
var database: FIRDatabase!
```

and on

```
// Create a chat message from a FIRDataSnapshot
func chatMessageFromSnapshot(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) -> ChatMessage? {
    let data = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
    guard let name = data["name"] as String! else { return nil }
    guard let message = data["message"] as String! else { return nil }
    let chatMessage = ChatMessage(name: name, message: message, image: nil)
    return chatMessage
}
```

I'm new to Firebase and want to learn, but the examples gives me errors each time a try or somthing is missing in the documentation...

FIRDatabase and FIRDataSnapshot are giving error: Use of undeclared type 'FIRDataSnapshot' and Use of undeclared type 'FIRDatabase'

Comment: Were you sure to importFirebaseimportFirebaseimport Firebase at the top of your Swift file? Also, be sure to install Firebase via a Podfile.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I have imported FireBase at top of my Swift file and this is my Podfile : pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'

Comment: And with or without Pod 'Firebase' When I import FirebaseDatabase in my swift file I get this error; Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: Also check out [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/firebase-talk/7U9WipcWo_o/pqq_VbOtBAAJ). Mike says this happens if your CocoaPods master repo isn't synced. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 8):

Try only importing the frameworks that you need, and not the generic firebase. So if your import looks like this:

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseAnalytics
import FirebaseDatabase
```

try with just

```
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseAnalytics
import FirebaseDatabase
```

Comment: Two years later, and this is still solid advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has crappy documentation and API, as it is true for almost every Google product. Check if retrieved FIRDataSnapshot snapshot has value of [NSNull null] object, not a ‘nil’ as it is stated in their mistaken documentation